# Concatenate two NumPy arrays X and Y

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a data set X and Y imported from numpy like this

```py
datasetX = [[2,2],  [1,2],  [3,4],  [1,1],  [3,3],  [7,2],  [5,2],  [6,1],  [8,0],  [7,3]]

datasetY = [0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]
```

And I would like to concatenate to the following, how can I achieve it?

```
dataset = [[2,2,0],
    [1,2,0],
    [3,4,0],
    [1,1,0],
    [3,3,0],
    [7,2,1],
    [5,2,1],
    [6,1,1],
    [8,0,1],
    [7,3,1]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`np.column_stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html): `np.column_stack([datasetX, datasetY])`

or [`np.hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html): `np.hstack([datasetX, datasetY[:, None]])`

Answer (score -2):

create a loop to cycle through the arrays adding y values to x.

```
for x in datasetX:
   datasetX[x].append(datasetY[x])
```

Comment: There are better ways to concatenate arrays in numpy than using `for` loops. `for` loops are generally an anti-pattern in numpy

Comment: `numpy` is not designed for iterations, this is slow.

Comment: @mathfux Thanks for reminding me that, what if I want to loop over a numpy array, what should I do?

Comment: @user16971617 Try to use `numpy` methods instead. They perform loops under the hood in C level but they are designed to process all the items of specific arrays (or sub arrays). These are called 'vectorised actions'. If you can't avoid iterations, `numpy` might not be a good option.

Comment: @user16971617 I mean `numpy` is hardly applicable in problems of graph theory or combinatorics where there is no easy way predict where will iteration stop.